# Atom Package - Unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: package, atom-editor

I've just installed the Atom text editor. When I try to install my first package I get the following error:-

```
"Unable to verify the first certificate"
```

This happens when trying to search for the package e.g. Emmet, AtomLinter. I've restarted my machine but I still get the same error message.

My npm and apm configuration settings are as follows :-

```
$ npm config list && apm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.5.1 node/v8.9.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\edwarm4\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://proxy2.nttvpn.via.novonet:80/"
proxy = "http://proxy2.nttvpn.via.novonet:80/"
strict-ssl = false

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "D:\\AppData\\edwarm4\\Application Data\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Program Files\Git
; HOME = C:\Users\edwarm4
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

; cli configs
globalconfig = "C:\\Users\\edwarm4\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc"
user-agent = "npm/3.10.10 node/v6.9.5 win32 x64"
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\edwarm4\\.atom\\.apmrc"

; environment configs
node-gyp = "C:/Users/edwarm4/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.25.0/resources/app/apm/bin                                                                                                                                                                                               /../node_modules/.bin/node-gyp"
python = "C:/Users/edwarm4/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.25.0/resources/app/apm/bin/p                                                                                                                                                                                               ython-interceptor.sh"

; userconfig C:\Users\edwarm4\.atom\.apmrc
https-proxy = "http://proxy2.nttvpn.via.novonet:80/"
proxy = "http://proxy2.nttvpn.via.novonet:80/"
strict-ssl = false

; globalconfig C:\Users\edwarm4\.atom\.apm\.apmrc
cache = "C:\\Users\\edwarm4\\.atom\\.apm"
progress = false

; node bin location = C:\Users\edwarm4\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.25.0\resources\a                                                                                                                                                                                               pp\apm\bin\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Program Files\Git
; HOME = C:\Users\edwarm4
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of these worked. I have AdGuard installed and had to perform the following (Running on Windows 11):

- Exclude Atom app from filtering by entering the full Atom app path in AdGuard > General Settings > Advanced Settings.
- - App Path is generally: "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe"
- Also, you need to add " atom.io " to the HTTPS Exclusions list. (Settings -> Network -> HTTPS filtering -> Exclustions -> + add atom.io -> Then click save).

This made it work for me with no other configuration changes. If you do not have AdGuard or other application of this type installed, then there may be other anti-virus/Anti-malware applications you may need to exclude this app from.

Answer (score 1):

With `strict-ssl = false` set, perhaps using the command line will work?

e.g.

`apm search package-name`

`apm install package-name`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10, temporarily turn off Ransomware Protection.  RP running will cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I turned off Fiddler and it worked.

Thanks to atorstling on GitHub for mentioning this solution:
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/16361#issuecomment-454049768

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution in the official Atom repo: [link](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/103#issuecomment-131932623)

However, for me it was enough to turn off the VPN and install worked.